# Azure Machine Learning Experiment Creation

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to create Experiments in Azure ML. I want to done a sample and small POC on Azure ML.

I have a data for the students consisting of StudentID, Student Name and Marks for Monthly Tests 1,2 and 3. I just to want to Predict data for the Final Monthly Test (i.e., Monthly Test 4).

I don't know how to create and what kind of Transformations to be used in Predicting the Data.

Anyone Please...

Thanks in Advance
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start with basic tutorials.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/machine-learning-create-experiment/

It is real helpful. I also referred this.
You can draw simple flow chart for your experiment and simply apply when you need to drag the dataset.

HTH

Comment: I already gone through this URL. But i didn't get the prediction what we expect. Could you please help me out in detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unsupervised machine learning problem. Do refer the algorithms that you can use for solving the problem (Most probably linear regression will suit for this case) Do the data pre-processing first. Then follow the steps in the above link mentioned by @kunal to build up the model.

Comment: I am implementing Linear regression to solve the problem. Also, i am explaining how i created an experiment in ML. Load the input data from an excel by using the Dataset.And apply Linear Regression on the Train Model and Score Model.

Comment: So do you get succeeded with the process?